# Rails validations if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements

I need your help validating a simple Rails model.

First i want to check if the user filled all input-fields:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base

   validates :firstname, :lastname, :firstvalue, :secondvalue, presence: true

   [...]
```

I also want to check if the `:secondvalue` param is bigger than `:firstvalue`.

Adding

```
validate :biggerThan

def biggerThan

    if self.secondvalue < self.firstvalue

        errors.add(:secondvalue, "must be bigger than First")

    end
end
```

Well this works, but only if all other fields are filled! Creating a new Entry leaving all fields blank i am getting an `undefined method <' for nil:NilClass`.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
validate :biggerThan, if: Proc.new{ |test| test.firstvalue.present? and test.secondvalue.present? }
```

It would be good if you add `numericality` validations also

```
validates :firstvalue, numericality: true
validates :secondvalue, numericality: true
```